# How to add correctly spacy regex patterns to jsonl file

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I have a working regex pattern that I want to use in tagging NamedEntity Recognition and finding it using spacy.
I store this in `.jsonl` file that I read with `.from_disk` method

Here is a working example in python:

```
import re
pattern = '(RAS?[\S]+)' # I want to find all strings starting with RAS and ending right before space or similar character
words = ['RAS', 'RAS', 'su RAS s:', 'SuRASs:', 'suRASs dfas:', 'raSan']
[re.findall(pattern, x) for x in words]

Out[7]: [['RAS'], ['RAS'], ['RAS'], ['RASs:'], ['RASs'], []]
```

But when I try to use the regex pattern in jsonl file and add it to the NamedEntityRecognizer, I get an error:

`ValueError: Invalid JSON on line 1: {"label": "REFERENCE_TLC", "pattern": [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "(RAS?[\S]+)"}}]}`

Do you know if spacy has some limitation is use of regexes?

Because when I use this regex `(RAS)`, it works, but doesn't find me the cases I need

Here is official `spacy` regex example in their documentation, but it doesn't help me: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex

Comment: You should self document by answering your own question in the answer part rather than editing it here

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I separated the answer from the original question now.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution myself, but in case it happens to somebody else, I would leave this question here.

The correct regex for this case should be `"RAS?.+"`, that matches everything after `RAS`. The reason I found in reading spacy documentation more closely: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex

From this section: When using the REGEX operator, keep in mind that it operates on single tokens, not the whole text. Each expression you provide will be matched on a token.

As my text is already tokenized, there is no such thing as until next space or until end of the nonspace characters. I already have tokens without spaces... Silly me for not noticing this earlier, when it was written as Important Note :facepalm: